# C++ Sqlite3 , executing 2 sql statement - the 2nd statement get Segmentation Core Dump Error

Tags: c++, sqlite

I tried to do the following.

After add record, i will select from the same table to get the userid which is auto increment and primary key. but I get segmentation core dump when I try to do the following

The insert code work, but when I try to execute the select statement, thats where my code result in the error. I am trying to get userid field from database and assign it to a string or vector result[0];

My test2.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <vector>

//g++ -o test2 test2.cpp -lsqlite3
using namespace std;

string quotesql( const string& s ) {
    return string("'") + s + string("'");
}


int main()
{
int counter = 0;

    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt, * stmt2;

string name = "Kungfu Panda2";
string department = "normal";
string password = "hellopassword";

string sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO abe_account (name,department,password) VALUES ("
+quotesql(name) + ","
+quotesql(department) + ","
+quotesql(password) + ");";


    if (sqlite3_open("abeserver.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    sqlite3_prepare( db, sqlstatement.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL );//preparing the statement
    sqlite3_step( stmt );//executing the statement
        }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to open db\n";
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

//after insert ,we select back to get the user id;

sqlstatement = "select * from abe_account where name="
+quotesql(name) + " AND department=" 
+quotesql(department)+";";

    sqlite3_prepare( db, sqlstatement.c_str(), -1, &stmt2, NULL );//preparing the statement
    sqlite3_step( stmt2 );//executing the statement


std::vector< std::vector < std:: string > > result;

while( sqlite3_column_text( stmt2, 0 ) )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    result[i].push_back( std::string( (char *)sqlite3_column_text( stmt2, i ) ) );
    sqlite3_step( stmt2 );
}


   //cout << result.size() << endl;



    sqlite3_finalize(stmt2);
    sqlite3_close(db);





    return 0;

}
```

How do I retrieve my data if I added successfully. I need to retrieve for the purpose of check my statement execute correctly, and also to get the userid which is auto increment and created as a primary key as I need cout to client that his userid is +userid+

If my vector usage for select statement is wrong, how can I achieve getting the user id after my insert statement is execute, my insert statement is working as I check my database , the record was added

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this call:

```
result[i].push_back(...);
```

`result` is a vector of vectors, but it's empty. So attempting to use `result[i]` results in a failure.

**Edit:**

Change the inner loop to something like this instead:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    result.push_back(vector<std::string>());
    result[i].push_back(...);
}
```

Maybe you mean something like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; sqlite3_column_text(stmt2, 0); i++ )
{
    result.push_back(vector<std::string>());

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        result[i].push_back(...);

    sqlite_step(stmt2);
}
```

Comment: But how do I retrieve my data if I added successfully. I need to retrieve for the purpose of check my statement execute correctly, and also to get the userid which is auto increment and created as a primary key as I need cout to client that his userid is +userid+

Comment: @user1595932 But you don't actually add anything to `result`, you try to add to `result[i]`. You need to use e.g. `result.push_back(...);` first.

Comment: I dont get it.. how do i change my code to make it able retrieve after successfully added the record?

Comment: @user1595932 I've added a couple of suggestions to my answer. However, I don't know it's something like that you want. But they will stop your program from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problem with the uninitialized nested `vector`s (see Joachim Pileborg's answer), you should not check the result of `sqlite3_column_text` in your loop condition. The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) states:

> If the SQL statement does not currently point to a valid row, or if the column index is out of range, the result is undefined.

I'd prefer to check the result of `sqlite3_step` in the while condition, like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector < std:: string > > result;

while(sqlite3_step(stmt2) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    result.push_back(vector<std::string>());

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
         result[i].push_back( std::string( (char *)sqlite3_column_text( stmt2, i ) ) );
    }
}
```

If you go with this approach, you have to remove the `sqlite3_step` a few lines above the loop.